# Get django user profile from python-social-auth

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

My Django project lets users log in with a Google or Facebook profile, using python-social-auth's django integration.

Once they've logged in, is there a way to get a link to their profile on Google or Facebook?  I'm trying to do something like this:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.mail import mail_admins

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def alert_new_user(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    social = instance.social_auth.last() # Assuming .last() gives me the one just added
    if social is not None:
        mail_admins('New user resistration',
            'A new user registered with name {}'.format(instance.get_full_name()),
            '<html><head/><body>A new user, <a href="{}">{}</a>, registered.</body></html>'.format(
                ???What goes here???, instance.get_full_name()
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a link to their Facebook profile before they are logged in.

In the `pipeline`, there is a function called `social_details` which get information about the user from specified social network.

If we take a look at that method, it is pretty simple:

```
def social_details(backend, details, response, *args, **kwargs):
    return {'details': dict(backend.get_user_details(response),
                            **details)}
```

and if you `print` the `response`:

```
def social_details(backend, details, response, *args, **kwargs):
    print(response)
    return {'details': dict(backend.get_user_details(response),
                            **details)}
```

you will see that there is a parameter `link`, provided login is through Facbook. Now you can get that `link` and save/use it however you want.